# Runtime exec launch application in background java

Tags: java, swing

when I run the following code, the notepad is getting launched in background instead of foreground

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    rt.exec("notepad.exe");
} catch (IOException ex) {
}
```

Example:

From my java desktop application, I am trying to launch "notepad.exe". The notepad is getting launched behind the application.

I would like to see that notepad should appear in foreground.

Could you please help me to resolve it?

Comment: I checked and it is launched foreground.

Comment: I have found out the reason why it is coming at my end. Navigate to JFrame->Properties and set "Always on Top" to true. then the app appears in background. If it is set to false then it appears in foreground.Anyhow Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `Desktop.getDesktop().open(File)` is probably a lot easier. However if persisting with a `Process`.. Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The following will open both files and executables (.exe):

Java 1.6 and above:

```
try {
   Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("notepad.exe"));
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Java 1.5 and under, without external library (windows only):

```
try {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"notepad.exe\"");
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I only tested the 1.5 solution with opening excel files but not with opening executable files, but I'm guessing it could work to.